# select part of the line from text file in powershell

Tags: file, select, powershell, text

Im trying to select part of the line from text file

i used `select-string -pattern "IM1"` to filter out but the outcome is like this :

> **19.la1:288:IM1=144_-_1.3.jpg;**

i just want the outcome to be from **=** to **;** so only 144_-_1.3.jpg would appear

jpg files would have different names and lengths

Answer (score 4):

You can split the line on the equel sign, get the last element (-1), and trim the semicolon:

```
PS> $line.Split('=')[-1].Trim(';')
144_-_1.3.jpg
```

Comment: i thought it would be easier, i started my adventure with powershell today and i have no idea how to get this working, anyway thanks for your answer

Comment: I agree that the syntax may look cryptic to a beginner at first but I can assure you that it is meaning full once you learn the rules and you'll also find out that it's very awkward to do in other scripting languages. Let me know if you need further help with this

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regular expression:

```
$line='19.la1:288:IM1=144_-_1.3.jpg'
$regex = [regex]'={1}(.*\.jpg)'
$regex.Match($line).Groups[1].Value
```